# "It was possible for me to proceed to the..... "

Tags: grammar

"It was possible for me to proceed to the US for my graduate studies because I was offered a scholarship". Is this sentence grammatically correct?  Should it be "It became possible..... " Or are they both ccorrect?

Comment: This is a non-idiomatic usage of "to proceed". If you already traveled to the US, say "to come". If not, say "to go".

Comment: I'd suggest the more concise, "I was able to come to the U.S. for graduate school because I was offered a scholarship."

Answer (score 1):

"It became possible..." means that "it began to be possible" according to the definition of become from the OED. If the "scholarship" was what initiated the allowance of your "proceed[ing] to the US" then this would be a the more applicable wording; i.e. *become* would indicate a development of some kind and that the "scholarship" functioned as a contingency in determining the outcome of the situation while other factors are also present.

"It was possible..." suggest that the "scholarship" alone accounted for you ability to move "to the US." This also does not imply any change or development, whereas the word *become* does.

In this particular scenario, **"became"** would be the more suitable word; although both are grammatically correct. This is because at one point it was not possible for you to "proceed to the US" and through the development of the "scholarship" it "became" possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it was possible, is it still possible now? It might be a slightly better choice to say "it became possible" in this particular case since something happened that change its possibility for the better, although both are grammatically correct.